# Deploy React App using Auth0 Authentication to netlify

Tags: reactjs, auth0, netlify

I have created a react app using Auth0 and everything works fine locally. But when I deploy to heroku, Auth0 no longer works.

Note:I have added the deployed link to the following in the application - Allowed Callback URLs, Allowed Logout URLs, Allowed web origins.

Still it doesn't work: https://seams.netlify.app/

```
This is the error I get:https://undefined/authorize?redirect_uri=
```

This is where the redirect is coming from

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjB8e.png)

Comment: You need to provide more info, code snippets and actual application logs. 
Giving a link to see it does not work isn't helping us much. I  too stumble upon a lot of websites that don't work but i can't tell why. What we need is the code where you are calling/configuring the authentication. 
Also note that posting links like the one you did is discouraged since in a month the link may be dead and people coming to this question will be left clueless about what we were  talking.

Comment: A symptom seems to be the fact that when you press login the domain changes to  `https://undefined/authorize?redirect_uri=` (see the undefined). What causes that though I can't say without more info of your code.

Comment: Here is a snippet of the redirect code

**
` <Auth0Provider
    domain={domain}
    clientId={clientId}
    redirectUri={window.location.origin}
  >
    <App />
  </Auth0Provider>`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your `clientId` and `domain` hold the value of the environment variables `REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID` and `REACT_APP_AUTHO_DOMAIN`. These need to be configured in the environment where you're deploying. In your localhost , you do that in `.env` file mostly. In your deployment environment, a **UI** generally exists that can help you do the same. So you can search for how to do the same in **netlify**.

Here is the documentation that will help you - https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/?_ga=2.167654334.1252444955.1614077370-1741414160.1614077370

The below step has worked in the past seamlessly for me :-

> In Site settings > Build & deploy > Environment > Environment
> variables. Variable values set under site settings will override the
> team-level settings.

Comment: This worked. I failed to add my variables to Netlify's variable environment and that was why it kept failing. Thank you.